# Xero api mixed tax input

Tags: xero-api

Our application allows the user to enter a receipt.

The receipt is for $1010 and only a portion of this attracts GST, say $10.

When we are writing to the api, it tries to calculate GST:

And an error occurs:

```
The specified TaxAmount -10.00 does not match the calculated tax amount -91.82 for the specified TaxType and LineAmountTypes
```

Is there a way to turn this validation off?

We can add two lines one with the GST and one without. but don't want to have to reeducate the user if we don't have to.

Happy Xero'ing